# How to use boost::intrusive_ptr for private nested class within class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost

Suppose I have a `list` class:

```
template<typename T>
class list {
    ...

private:
    class node {
        ...

    private:
        std::size_t refcount_;

        // friends of node because accessing private member refcount_
        friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(const node* p) noexcept;
        friend void intrusive_ptr_release(const node* p) noexcept;            
    };

    // friends of list because accessing private nested class node
    friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(const node* p) noexcept;
    friend void intrusive_ptr_release(const node* p) noexcept;

    boost::intrusive_ptr<node> node_{new node};
};

template<typename T>
void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(const typename list<T>::node* p) noexcept
{ ... }

template<typename T>
void intrusive_ptr_release(const typename list<T>::node* p) noexcept
{ ... }

list<int> xs;  // error
```

The code above doesn't compile. The error was undefined symbols for `intrusive_ptr_add_ref(list<int>::node const*)` and `intrusive_ptr_release(list<int>::node const*)`.

I think the problem is probably that I'm declaring non-template functions as friends in `list` and `node`, but what I defined are function templates. So what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Didn't you asked this recently? Am I having deja vúe's?

Comment: declare intrusive_ptr_add_ref before you declare it to be a friend. template functions are funny like that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ he asked a question on a similar topic

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No I didn't. :-)

Comment: @RichardHodges Umm...how can I declare `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` before declaring its parameter type?

Comment: @ZizhengTai you can declare template functions before you define them. You need to have at least declared the generic form before the class that befriends the template function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those occasions where inline friend definitions shine:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1d26ed079af838e)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>

template<typename T> class list {
    class node {
        std::size_t mutable refcount_;

        // friends of list because accessing private nested class node
        friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(node const* p) noexcept {
            p->refcount_ += 1;
        }
        friend void intrusive_ptr_release(node const* p) noexcept {
            if (--p->refcount_)
                return;
            std::cout << "freeing node " << static_cast<void const*>(p) << "\n";
        }
    };

    boost::intrusive_ptr<node> node_{new node};
};

int main() {
    list<int> xs;
}
```

Prints

```
freeing node 0x19b7c20
```

or similar

### BONUS POINTS

If you want to go the verbose route, I'd suggest the sanest way is to have the base-template parameterized on the Node type, not the list-element (because partial specializations don't go with function templates).

Here's something that also works:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da240581290fa4a6)</kbd>**

```
template <typename Node, typename = typename Node::is_my_list_impl_nodetype> void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(Node const*) noexcept;
template <typename Node, typename = typename Node::is_my_list_impl_nodetype> void intrusive_ptr_release(Node const*) noexcept;

template<typename T> class list {
    class node {
        using is_my_list_impl_nodetype = std::true_type;

        std::size_t mutable refcount_;

        // friends of list because accessing private nested class node
        friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref<node, std::true_type>(node const* p) noexcept;
        friend void intrusive_ptr_release<node, std::true_type>(node const* p) noexcept;
    };

    boost::intrusive_ptr<node> node_{new node};
};

template<typename Node, typename>
void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(Node const* p) noexcept {
    p->refcount_ += 1;
}

template<typename Node, typename>
void intrusive_ptr_release(Node const* p) noexcept {
    if (--p->refcount_)
        return;
    std::cout << "freeing node " << static_cast<void const*>(p) << "\n";
}
```

The whole [SFINAE on `is_my_list_impl_nodetype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) is to prevent an open template from creating ambiguous overloads if you have more intrusive pointer usages in your translation unit that use other addref/release methods.

Comment: For bonus points sketched a more verbose take that doesn't use the elegance of inline friend definitions: [using SFINAE-ed base-template](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da240581290fa4a6)

Comment: When you define the friend functions inside the body of `list<T>::node`, do they become `list<T>`'s friend of `list<T>::node`'s friend, or both's?

Comment: @ZizhengTai Only node's ([proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4352300cf72f4c25)). But it's easy to add: [fixed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a4a3fd73d7ed5dd)